# Converting a pandas Series of string ints into a numpy matrix - efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series, each cell containts a string of ints (same number of ints in each string, seperated by a space),  e.g.

```
s = pd.Series(['1 17 -3 ... n'],['100 -27 344 ... n'],...,['0 14 2 ... n'])
```

I know how to convert a single cell into a numpy vector:

```
arr = np.asarray(s[0].split(' '), dtype = np.float32)
```

I also know how to convert the whole series into a matrix, which is my finel goal:

```
X = np.zeros((len(s), number_of_ints_in_string))
for i, cell in enumerate(s):
    X[i,:] = np.asarray(cell.split(' '), dtype = np.float32)
```

the problem is that for a very long series (which is my case), this is slow. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: the brackets on the `s` expression don't look right.

Comment: One way or other you'll have to use `string.split` on each string.  In `pandas` the elements of that Series are Python strings.   Even the `np.char.split` function uses Python string methods.  So there isn't a faster `whole-array` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` to DataFrame and then conver it to `numpy array` by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['1 17 -3','100 -27 344','0 14 2'])
print (s)
0        1 17 -3
1    100 -27 344
2         0 14 2
dtype: object

arr = s.str.split(expand=True).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)
print (arr)
[[  1.  17.  -3.]
 [100. -27. 344.]
 [  0.  14.   2.]]
```

Another idea is use list comprehension:

```
arr = np.asarray([x.split() for x in s], dtype = np.float32)
print (arr)
[[  1.  17.  -3.]
 [100. -27. 344.]
 [  0.  14.   2.]]
```

Second solution is faster it 300k rows:

```
s = pd.Series(['1 17 -3','100 -27 344','0 14 2'])
s = pd.concat([s] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


In [52]: %timeit np.asarray([x.split() for x in s], dtype = np.float32)
521 ms ± 10.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [53]: %timeit s.str.split(expand=True).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)
939 ms ± 6.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```